# Tensorflow - Grouping placeholders by batch index

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, slice, tensor

Given a network with two or more placeholders of varying dimensionality e.g.

```
x1 = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, seq_len])
x2 = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, seq_len])
xn = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, None, seq_len]
```

The first dimension in each placeholder corresponds to the minibatch size. `seq_len` is the length of the inputs. The second dimension is like a list of inputs that I need to process together with `x1` and `x2` for each index in the minibatch. How can I group these tensors to operate on them by batch index?

For example

```
x1 = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
x2 = [[7, 8, 9], [8, 7, 6]]
xn = [[[1, 5, 2], [7, 2, 8], [3, 2, 5]], [[8, 9, 8]]]
```

I need to keep `x1[0] i.e. [1, 2, 3]`, `x2[0] i.e. [7, 8, 9]`, and `xn[0] i.e. [[1, 5, 2], [7, 2, 8], [3, 2, 5]]` together, because I need to perform matrix operations between `x1[i]` and each element in `xn[i]` for all `i`.

Notice that the dimensionality of `xn` is *jagged.*

Comment: What is the question exactly?

Comment: @ JonH `How can I group these tensors to operate on them by batch index.`

Comment: It looks like these are input data. Why not group x1[0], x[2], xn[0] together in your pre-processing? Otherwise you might need to use slicing to get the element from each batch and rely on a loop to process those groups.

Comment: @greeness, I think they are already grouped together by batch index. It's just that I need to pass the inputs in `xn` through the same architecture as `x1` and `x2` for each batch idx, but the 3D vs 2D issue is causing problems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Still not sure if I understand your question. If I understand correctly, your challenge comes from the jagged nature of the dimensionality of `xn`. I have the below way to "unrolling" along batch index. The result is an array with a size of batch_size; each element in the array is a Tensor. Of course you can perform other operations for all these individual tensors before evaluating them.

I have to use [`tf.scan`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/scan) to perform the operation for each element of `xn[i]` because its first dimension is dynamic. There might exist better solutions though.

```
x1 = np.array([[1, 2, 3]])
xn = np.array([[[1, 5, 2], [7, 2, 8], [3, 2, 5]]])

batch_size = x1.shape[0]

result = []
for batch_idx in range(batch_size):
  x1_i = x1[batch_idx]
  xn_i = xn[batch_idx]
  result.append(tf.scan(fn=lambda a, x: x * x1_i, elems=xn_i, initializer=x1_i))
with tf.Session() as sess:
  print sess.run([result[0]])

# result, this is x1[0] multiply each element in xn[0] for all i (element-wise). 
# free free to plug in your own matrix operations in the `fn` arg of `tf.scan`.
  [array([[ 1,  10, 6],
          [ 7,  4, 24],
          [ 3,  4, 15]])]
```

Comment: Thanks for suggesting `tf.scan`. I've also been looking into `tf.tile`.